# For each row, assign character to first highest value in that row

Tags: r, algorithm, loops

In my data, people (id) rate (1-3) topics (A, B, C, D, E). I would like to allocate ids to their hightest rating topics. I calculated "popularity" of topics as the sum of maximum value ratings, e.g. topic B only has one 3-star rating whereas topic A has three 3-star ratings.

Now, I am looking for a loop that solves the following (assume data is already arranged by `popularity`):

- For each row find the first occurence (there will be ambiguity) of max value in that row. (Do not count `popularity`).
- Save the resulting row-column combination, e.g. replace topic character to this first max value occurence and set all values in that row `NA`.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    data <- data.frame(topic = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
               id1 = c(1,2,3,1,2), 
               id2 = c(3,3,2,1,3),
               id3 = c(1,1,3,3,2),
               id4 = c(3,1,2,2,1),
               id5 = c(2,2,1,3,1),
               id6 = c(3,1,1,1,3)) %>% 
      mutate(popularity= rowSums(. == 3),) %>%
      arrange(popularity)
    
    # Initial Data
      topic id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 popularity
    1     B   2   3   1   1   2   1         1
    2     C   3   2   3   2   1   1         2
    3     D   1   1   3   2   3   1         2
    4     E   2   3   2   1   1   3         2
    5     A   1   3   1   3   2   3         3
    
    # After one step of the loop
      topic id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 popularity
    1     B   NA  B   NA  NA  NA  NA        1
    2     C   3   2   3   2   1   1         2
    3     D   1   1   3   2   3   1         2
    4     E   2   3   2   1   1   3         2
    5     A   1   3   1   3   2   3         3
    
    # After second step of the loop
      topic id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 popularity
    1     B   NA  B   NA  NA  NA  NA        1
    2     C   C   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA        2
    3     D   1   1   3   2   3   1         2
    4     E   2   3   2   1   1   3         2
    5     A   1   3   1   3   2   3         3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this without a loop by using the vectorized `max.col` to find the column index for each row where the `max` value of 'id' columns are.  Then, `cbind` with sequence of rows and the column index to a temporary `matrix` created to assign values from 'topic' column.  Assign that template dataset to the 'id' columns of 'data'

```
i1 <- startsWith(names(data), "id")
m1 <- matrix(NA, nrow(data), sum(i1))
m1[cbind(seq_len(nrow(m1)), max.col(data[i1], 'first'))] <- data$topic
data[i1] <- m1
```

-output

```
data
#  topic  id1  id2  id3  id4  id5  id6 popularity
#1     B <NA>    B <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>          1
#2     C    C <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>          2
#3     D <NA> <NA>    D <NA> <NA> <NA>          2
#4     E <NA>    E <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>          2
#5     A <NA>    A <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>          3
```

Comment: That looks excellent, let me think about it.